# how to select posts by particular author? (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a page with template `No Sidebars` I want to list 5 posts' titles on that page by author where the author's name = page's title

any idea how to do so without using any plugin?

I thought that [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function would do the trick but [this important note](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Important_note) kind of tells me that I cannot use query_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of code that will probably get you the Post Titles by author; in order to have this automatically feed off of the page title I'd have your title generation code... Hope this helps you get at least part of the way there...

```
  <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('author_name=YourAuthor&showposts=5'); ?>
  <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
  <?php the_title(); ?></a><?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Function Reference/WP Query « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) and an earlier answer (with the same code :) as poindexter's) at [Wordpress display featured posts outside of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646767/wordpress-display-featured-posts-outside-of-loop)